# Turn on flashlight when volume button is held

Tags: tasker, volume-control, buttons, camera-flash

I have Nexus 4 on Android 5.0 Lollipop, and I'm using Tasker. Is there any way to get the Flashlight to turn on when screen is off and the volume up or down button is held for 2-3 seconds? Then turn off the flashlight if the button is held again.

I know there's a `%SCREEN` variable for the screen part, but how can I detect if a volume button is held?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to detect a Volume Up/Down button press for 'n' seconds, so I would give an alternate  solution. You would have to install [Xposed Additions Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb.pro) and [TeslaLED Flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.flashlight). The former needs root access and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) installed.

## Instructions

1. Visit my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277). Under the heading "*Instructions for Xposed Additions*" follow steps 1-6.
2. For step 7, choose **Screen Off** instead of others.
3. Tap the newly created entry, activate **Long Press** by ticking the check-box, then tap on **Long Press**.
4. Scroll down and select **Shortcut** → **TeslaLED Toggle**. It will show a screen like:

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
5. Also, the delay of 2-3 seconds is way too large in my opinion. Anyhow, the app doesn't allow long press delay more than 500ms and you may configure in [step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy8lX.png) of my linked answer. I settled for 250ms.

You may use Tasker instead of using the TeslaLED app (officially [recommended](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html)) but there is no guarantee that the native method would work. In fact, some users reported that even the latter app didn't work for them.

The action in Tasker to activate torch is **Alert → Torch**. It would show up in red color if it's not supported on your device.

There are some other ways mention in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/2n6pgs/is_there_a_way_to_control_nexus_5_torch_toggle/) which seems to be device specific but nonetheless could give you a lead for better web search results.

For example, in my One Plus One running CM12 there is no class named `camera`  let alone a file `/sys/class/camera/flash/rear_flash`. But it does have a class `leds` and the file `/sys/class/leds/led:flash_torch/brightness` too. The default torch brightness in my device is set to 53 instead of 100.

---

I also tried the Tasker plugin [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) but it doesn't seem to support long press hardware buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Tasker cannot turn the flashlight on by Alert>Torch. Torch is not available at Lolipop or better.